# Duplicate Front Boxes sound onto Rear Speakers

Tags: windows, windows-8, audio, speakers, foobar2000

I am currently using foobar2000 which has the ability to "Convert Stereo to 4 Channels" by simply duplicating the Front Speakers output to the Rear Speakers.

This Sounds really great opposed to the "Speaker Fill" Option in my Realtek HD driver, which only seems to copy certain frequences (e.g. no voice) to the Rear Speakers. This sounds horrible.

What i want is to have the foobar2000 thing for all my application when there is no 5.1 sound available.

Is there a software that can archieve this in Windows 8 x64?

Comment: Not really a duplicate since i want way more specific things..

Comment: @NickRussler it's about as close as you're going to get unless your sound card **driver** explicitly supports it.  Otherwise, this has to be done on a per-application basis which supports 2.1-5.1 upmixing.  Alternatively, you could just get a splitter and output the same signal to both the front and back speaker pairs...